# unexpected char in manifest file

Tags: json, google-chrome-extension, scripting, manifest

I've been making this chrome extension for a while now. It's finally done and i went to upload it. Then it went "manifest.json:5:23: unexpected char. Can someone please help me figure out the mistake? i've tried almost everything but i cant seem to figure it out..

Heres the manifest.json file:

```
{    
        "name": "ROBLOX Catalog Helper v2",
    "version": "1.9.0", // version
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "description": "Notifies you whenever an item is selling for under its RAP", 
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "icon.png"

    },
    "permissions": [
    "alarms",
    "background",
    "debugger",
    "notifications",
    "cookies",
    "https://www.roblox.com/"
],
"background": {
    "scripts": ["bgWork.js", "jQuery-very3.js"]
},
"icons": { "16": "icon_png",
       "48": "icon_png",
      "128": "icon_png" }
}
```

Comment: Could it be that "// comment" in there?

Comment: Yeah it was! thank you so much :)